# Is there a maximum limit to the number of blocks a piston can push?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

For example: could you effectively push a line of blocks off into the distance? Is it limited by the loaded chunks? Or a shorter upper limit countable in blocks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

12 blocks is the maximum.
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pistons

Answer (score -3):

I learned it is between 12-15 blocks depending on the block.

Comment: Are you sure that they can ever push over 12 blocks?

Comment: Any evidence or hints on which blocks can be pushed beyond the 12 maximum the wiki lists?

Comment: As far as I know >12 is a wrong answer. unless you have proof and we can reproduce this.